# Mock the Model Mapper Strict Strategy in java

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I need to mock the following Model Mapper Strict strategy configuration with the mockito.

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
```

I tried the following in my test method but i am getting Null Pointer Exception.

```
@Test
public void mockModelMapper(){
    when(modelmapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT))
    .thenReturn(modelmapper.getConfiguration());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you modify the code examples to answer the following questions:  How do you setup the mock? Do you pass mock as configuration to modelMapper? Like this? `modelMapper.setConfiguration(Mockito.mock(Configuration.class))`

Comment: You can't double chain with mockito, `when(modelmapper.getConfiguration()).thenReturn(AConfig)` then the config can also be mocked to do what you want. But, I doubt `thenReturn` from a setter should return something from a mock call. Maybe I'm wrong tho

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @DCTID, you can't chain the mocks.  You need to split each method call and inject a mock for the object returned by getConfiguration().

```
@Test
public void mockModelMapper(){
    // Inject the configuration mock
    Configuration configurationMock = mock(Configuration.class);
    when(configurationMock.setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStragegies.STRICT)
        .thenReturn(configuraitonMock);

    when(modelmapper.getConfiguration()).thenReturn(configurationMock);
}
```